# Error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string, program crash

Tags: java, android

I have implemented an app that takes readings from a user and returns a message however on trying to open the activity the following error occurs:

```
2019-04-21 10:03:27.179 4338-4338/com.example.mymedicare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mymedicare, PID: 4338
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mymedicare/com.example.mymedicare.enteringReadings}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:620)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
        at com.example.mymedicare.enteringReadings.onCreate(enteringReadings.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770
```

```
public class enteringReadings extends AppCompatActivity {

private MyDBHelper db;
//declares values
private Button Enter;
private EditText Temprature;
private EditText lowerBlood;
private EditText higherBlood;
private EditText heartBeat;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_entering_readings);

    //Reads values as integers
    Temprature = findViewById(R.id.Temprature);
    int temprature =Integer.parseInt( Temprature.getText().toString());
    lowerBlood = findViewById(R.id.lowerBlood);
    int Lowerblood =Integer.parseInt( lowerBlood.getText().toString());
    higherBlood = findViewById(R.id.higherBlood);
    int Higherblood =Integer.parseInt( higherBlood.getText().toString());
    heartBeat = findViewById(R.id.heartBeat);
    int Heartbeat =Integer.parseInt( heartBeat.getText().toString());

    Button Enter = findViewById(R.id.Enter);
    db = new MyDBHelper(this);

    Enter.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

    if (temprature <= 37 && Lowerblood <=80 && Higherblood <=120 && Heartbeat <= 72 );
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your readings are fine no action required",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
}
```

I expect the app to allow the user to enter their readings, I have not implemented the other 2 cases but noticed this error after trying to run the App.

Comment: One of these lines which contain the `Integer.parseInt`  is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Temprature.getText()` returns empty string. Empty string can't be cast to `Integer`.
Add `try-catch` block to your code to handle a `NumberFormatException`.

```
int temprature = 0;
try {
    temprature = Integer.parseInt(Temprature.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   // Log error, change value of temperature, or do nothing
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it still throws the same error, is there any way to implement this by using the edit text as a number?

Comment: @BradleighJL You should add `try-catch` block for a every `Integer.parseInt` method.

Comment: Tried that before and get this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mymedicare/com.example.mymedicare.enteringReadings}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.mymedicare.enteringReadings cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener

Comment: @BradleighJL It is another crash. Your Activity doesn't implement OnClickListener interface.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see :

`ComponentInfo{com.example.mymedicare/com.example.mymedicare.enteringReadings}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

He's telling that you are trying to convert an empty string, you should give a value to your int at start for example.

```
Temprature = findViewById(R.id.Temprature);
    int temprature = 0;
    temprature =Integer.parseInt( Temprature.getText().toString());
```

So even if the editText will be empty, the system will pass a 0.

Otherwise if you need to pass the value only if the user select one, you can do it this way:

```
if (!Temprature.getText().toString().equals(""){
        temprature =Integer.parseInt( Temprature.getText().toString());

}else{
        Toast.makeText(context,"Please, select a value", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes I only want to pass the value when the user types it and then clicks the button so I will try to implement this now and let you know how I get on, would changing the edit texts to number be any easier?

Comment: Would be better, but don't forget to check if there's a valuer or not with an if, otherwise the program will pass a null value again, you can check this doing a thing like that: if( int != null){temprature = ecc...} happy easter and happy coding dude by the way :)

Comment: Thanks a lot and happy Easter to you too :)

Comment: Where exactly would I implement this?

Comment: Play around the lenght of the value for example: 
if(Temprature.getText().length() != 0) { //Do something}.
That will exclude any empty values!

Answer (score 0):

You should go with on click listener on any button where you should first check whether any box is empty or not, if it is empty you can't convert empty string to number as error is indicating.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class enteringReadings extends AppCompatActivity {

private MyDBHelper db;
//declares values
private Button Enter;
private EditText Temprature;
private EditText lowerBlood;
private EditText higherBlood;
private EditText heartBeat;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_entering_readings);
    Temprature = findViewById(R.id.Temprature);
    lowerBlood = findViewById(R.id.lowerBlood);
    higherBlood = findViewById(R.id.higherBlood);
    heartBeat = findViewById(R.id.heartBeat);

    //Reads values as integers


    Button Enter = findViewById(R.id.Enter);
    db = new MyDBHelper(this);

    //Enter.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
    Enter.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int temprature = 0;
            try {
                temprature = Integer.parseInt(Temprature.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Log error, change value of temperature, or do nothing
            }

            int Lowerblood = 0;
            try {
                Lowerblood = Integer.parseInt(lowerBlood.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Log error, change value of lowerBlood, or do nothing
            }

            int Higherblood = 0;
            try {
                Higherblood = Integer.parseInt(higherBlood.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Log error, change value of higherBlood, or do nothing
            }

            int Heartbeat = 0;
            try {
                Heartbeat = Integer.parseInt(heartBeat.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Log error, change value of heartBeat, or do nothing
            }
            if (temprature <= 37 && Lowerblood <= 80 && Higherblood <= 120 && Heartbeat <= 72) ;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your readings are fine no action required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

    });
}
```

}

Comment: That's how I got it working eventually I will accept the answer from @Andrew Churilo as that's what I used but it did need slightly editing. Thanks for all the replies everybody, highly appreciated and Happy Easter